# I want to hide table buttons

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have one table and in this table, I have two button Update and Disable I want to hide those buttons

I trying like this

```
 <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm" style=" overflow: auto;  ">
                 <tr>
                 <th>Dispatch Challan No</th>
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>From</th>
                  <?php
                  $hide = 'OFF';
                  if($hide == 'ON') { ?>
                  <th>Update</th>
                  <th>Delete</th>
                  <?php } ?>
                 </tr>

                 <?php foreach($dispatch as $dis){?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $dis->disp_ch_no;?></td>
                  <td><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($dis->disp_ch_date));?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $dis->from_branch_name;?></td>
                   <td><a class="btn btn-success btn-sm"  href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>booking/dispatch_challan/DispatchChallanController/updateDispatchChallanPage?disp_id=<?php echo $dis->disp_id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil" > Update</i></a></td>

                  <td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="delete_dispatch('<?php echo $dis->disp_id; ?>');"  title="Click here to delete your Dispatch record"><i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: #fff;"> Disable </i> </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php }?>
              </table>
```

this is my table

How can I hide these buttons

Comment: where is the `if()` ? try like `<?php if (isset($hide) and !empty($hide)) {?> `

Comment: @Sinto it gives me an error unexpected if

Comment: because you have added a `$hide` before that. remove it. Or put a `;`

Comment: @Sinto this is removed table header but I want to remove table record

Comment: <td><a class="btn btn-success btn-sm"  href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>booking/dispatch_challan/DispatchChallanController/updateDispatchChallanPage?disp_id=<?php echo $dis->disp_id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil" > Update</i></a></td>
                  
                  <td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="delete_dispatch('<?php echo $dis->disp_id; ?>');"  title="Click here to delete your Dispatch record"><i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: #fff;"> Disable </i> </a>
                    </td> this is my code

Comment: Yes, as I expected. You have to explain your issue properly in question. In this case, you have to add the condition in each row. If rows are in `for()` loop check the condition inside it. Paste your whole table section code above

Comment: @Sinto table added

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<?php
     $thswitch = 'OFF';
     if($thswitch == 'ON') { ?>
        <th>Update</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
<?php } ?>
```

whenever you want to show just $thswitch = 'ON'; it

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the `if ()` for each row as we did in `th`. Like:

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm" style="overflow: auto;">
    <tr>
        <th>Dispatch Challan No</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>From</th>
        <?php $hide = 'OFF';
            if ($hide == 'ON') { ?>
            <th>Update</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($dispatch as $dis) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td> <?php echo $dis->disp_ch_no;?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($dis->disp_ch_date));?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $dis->from_branch_name;?> </td>
        <?php if ($hide == 'ON') { ?>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>booking/dispatch_challan/DispatchChallanController/updateDispatchChallanPage?disp_id=<?php echo $dis->disp_id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil" > Update</i></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="delete_dispatch('<?php echo $dis->disp_id; ?>');" title="Click here to delete your Dispatch record"><i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: #fff;"> Disable </i> </a>
            </td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Or by using CSS you can hide this columns as:

Create a CSS class like:

```
.hidethisColumn { display: none !important; }
```

Use it in you table as:

```
<th class="<?=(($hide == 'ON')? 'hidethisColumn' : '')?>">Update</th>
<th class="<?=(($hide == 'ON')? 'hidethisColumn' : '')?>">Delete</th>
```

Similarly in rows inside `foreach()`:

```
<td class="<?=(($hide == 'ON')? 'hidethisColumn' : '')?>">
    <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>booking/dispatch_challan/DispatchChallanController/updateDispatchChallanPage?disp_id=<?php echo $dis->disp_id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil" > Update</i></a>
</td>
```

Comment: You are welcome. This is just the basic you should have to learn more.